# What determines the tcp length in a http packet?

Tags: http, tcp, http-headers

I have seen the tcp length is changing but not sure what made it,

32bytes
[image]

40bytes
[image]

Is it possible to set this fixed as 32bytes?

----updated----
I am not sure if MSS related to TCP length, which means 1460 gives 32 bytes?
[image]

Comment: Compare the differences?

Comment: not sure if I could make second one also as 32bytes?

Comment: Why do you want that? But my point was, that if you have two different packets, they're bound to have some differences which only you can compare given that your screenshots are cut off at the interesting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP header length can vary for a number of reasons.

The usual value is 40 bytes, but options such as SACK can result in longer headers, as specific sections of a stream are ACKed where packets have been dropped (or overly delayed).

HTTP in general has no interest or control over the size of the underlying transport (TCP) header.  These things tend to be set by the operating system TCP/IP stack, although some can be altered with iocontrols to the sockets.

Comment: I know MTU 1500 means MSS 1460, but does 1460 give 32 bytes? Or SACK is the key, without sniff tool, is it possible to calculate?

Comment: The size of the SACK option varies depending on how many chunks of the stream are being ACKed. MSS of 1460 is based on a nominal TCP header length of 40 which I think is actually the minimum